# Virtual function in a multiple inheritance class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

First of all apologies if this is a newbie question but I'm beginner at this.
My question is a variant of the diamond problem I believe.

Imagine I have the following classes:

```
class A{ public: virtual foo();};

class B{ public: foo();};

class C{ public: foo();};

class D: public A, public B, public C{
    public: foo();
};
```

My question is is it possible to call `foo()` from class `D` and have the virtual function run across `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. I have tried this but the `d::foo()` function overrides all the other `foo()` functions.

Or is it only possible if you make a 1:2 inheritance scheme?

```
class A{ public: virtual foo();};

class B: public A { public: foo();};

class C: public B { public: foo();};

class D: public C { public: foo();};
```

The reason I ask is because I would like to be able to construct `A`, `B` and `C` in different classes without having to construct each time also `A` or `B` or `C` but retain the possibility of running the virtual function without having to call for each case `A::foo()`, `B::foo()`, `C::foo()`.

Comment: "My question is is it possible to call foo() from class D and have the virtual function run across A, B, C and D" What do you mean?

Comment: Are you asking if you can call D.foo() and have it call A.foo(), B.foo() and C.foo() all at once?

Comment: Yes bstar55. I would like to call all of them at the same time. So calling D.foo() would call A.foo(), B.foo(), C.foo() and D.foo(). changed the question to try and be less confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **function overloading**, so you can not do what you want automatically.

You have to do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
  virtual void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo of A\n";
  }
};

class B {
 public:
  // virtual keyword is not needed,
  // but it's to write it so that you
  // remind the reader that foo is virtual
  virtual void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo of B\n";
  }
};

class C {
 public:
  virtual void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo of C\n";
  }
};

class D : public A, public B, public C {
 public:
  virtual void foo() {
    A::foo();
    B::foo();
    C::foo();
    std::cout << "foo of D\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  D d_object;
  d_object.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

However, I strongly suggest you to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764353/what-does-has-virtual-method-but-non-virtual-destructor-warning-mean-durin), since you probably receive:

`has virtual method..but not virtual constructor`

Usually warnings are wise to be treated like real errors, since they usually expose logical errors.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. This example could also be constructed without declaring a virtual function if I understand this correctly? Just by overloading the function foo().

Comment: @hadroque true. But you could just remove the `virtual` keyword and find out. I hope you understand now why this happening. You are welcome.

Comment: By the way I think the -1 in your question is too much for a beginner, so I am voting up for balancing @hadroque . :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to have to implement class `D::foo` explicitly call `A::foo()`, `B::foo()`, and `C::foo()`. There's no way to make it automatically call `foo()` on each parent class.